# TraitsUI CheckListEditor changing the case of values

Tags: python, enthought, traits, traitsui

I am using `CheckListEditor` to let user choose a subset of available options. With the style set to 'custom', it displays a list of check-list boxes with labels alongside. This is what I wanted. But, one problem is that, the text content is displayed with case changed in some cases - I am confused why this happens.

For eg, if the text is `".state.Last"`, it gets displayed as `".state.last"` .

Anyone know why this happens and if there is any workaround to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the editor calls the string method `capitalize` on the text.  I don't know why; perhaps the author thought this would help enforce a consistent style in the UI.

You can override this behavior with the `format_func` argument of the `CheckListEditor`.  Here's an example.  (I also used the `label` argument of the `Item` to override the capitalization of the editor's label.)

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, List, on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import Item, View, CheckListEditor


class Foo(HasTraits):
    stuff = List()

    traits_view = View(Item('stuff', style='custom', label='stuff',
        editor=CheckListEditor(values=['.state.First', '.state.Last', '.state.Any'],
                               format_func=lambda x: x)))

    @on_trait_change('stuff[]')
    def show_stuff(self):
        print "stuff =", self.stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo()
    f.configure_traits()
```

Alternatively, you can give the `values` as a list of tuples.  Each tuple has the form `(obj, label)`, where `label` is the string that is displayed in the UI and `obj` is the object added to the list.  When this form is used, the label is left unchanged in the UI.  For example,

```
    traits_view = View(Item('stuff', style='custom', label='stuff',
        editor=CheckListEditor(values=[('.state.First',)*2,
                                       ('.state.Last',)*2,
                                       ('.state.Any',)*2])))
```